# Xcode static analyzer performance when using singletons

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm having trouble understanding how the static analyzer in XCode is identifying possible leaks that involve singletons.  In the code below, I get warned that there is a possible leak in the first line, and also in the first return statement.  The analyzer places these warnings on the second return statement. Since I'm doing no allocations in these lines, I assume it is the access to the singleton, and its possible allocation, that is causing this warning. Can anyone explain to me what is going on here with the static analyzer?

```
        if ((self.tableView.editing & ([[[[GroupList sharedGroupList] newGroup] linkArray] count] < [[GrazeConstants sharedGrazeConstants] maxLinksPerGroup])) | 
            (([[[[GroupList sharedGroupList] newGroup] linkArray] count] == 0) & !self.tableView.editing)) {
            return ([[[[GroupList sharedGroupList] newGroup] linkArray] count]+1);
        } else {
            return ([[[[GroupList sharedGroupList] newGroup] linkArray] count]);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new`-prefixed methods are equivalent to an `alloc`+`init` pair according to Cocoa memory management conventions. The static analyzer is assuming that your `newGroup` method is returning an object with a +1 retain count, not an autoreleased one.

Rename the method (e.g., `group` or `makeGroup`), or add the [`NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED` attribute](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_ns_returns_not_retained) if you can't change the name.

Comment: Thanks.  I had noticed that there seemed to be a correlation with the new prefixed methods.  But I never dreamed that the analyzer is using names to assume behavior. Easily addressed.